# How to change text Amazon Linux AMI Test Page

Tags: linux

Whenever I start apache server(installed on EC2) it shows test page with heading "Amazon Linux AMI Test Page".
I want to change the wording with something like "Linux AMI - Started". (Note : I don't want to replace the complete page with my text, I want the same page but with heading "Linux AMI - Started" instead of "Amazon Linux AMI Test Page".
I have tried below but unfortunately its not working.

sed 's/Amazon Linux AMI Test Page/Linux AMI - Started/g'   /var/wwww/html/index.html

Could you please help or suggest some solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To actually perform the substitute "infile" and have the change reflected within the file itself, you will need to append the -i flag to the sed command and so:

```
sed -i 's/Amazon Linux AMI Test Page/Linux AMI - Started/g' /var/wwww/html/index.html
```